# How do I force yum to install without prompting the user, using bash?

Tags: bash, yum, rpm

I'm writing a bash script to install php5.4 and I'd like to automate this for a test VM. The rpm command I have is:

```
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el5/latest.rpm
yum install php54w
```

Now, in the middle of this running, there is a user prompt to enter [Y/N] whether or not to download the dependencies. So I either need to:

1. Simulate the user input of [Y]; or
2. pass in a command for yum not to ask and assume [Y]

What is the best method for a bash script and how do I accomplish both of the above?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

You can use the `-y` switch:

```
$ yum -y install php54w
```

*excerpt from the [yum man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/yum)*

```
-y, --assumeyes
      Assume yes; assume that the answer to any question which would be asked
      is yes. Configuration Option: assumeyes
```

Comment: Thank You. That was quick. Funny enough I was trying flags on rpm, and couldn't find it - but it makes sense that the yum is where it goes.